# Adding a binary file to resource in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

Please this might sound newbie - ish but I just couldn't get it to work since...

What is the steps to add a file (say file.exe) to resource in Visual Studio 2012 so that I can find the resource with `FindResource(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(idResource), MAKEINTRESOURCE(RC_BINARYTYPE));`

Please I have tried Going to the Resource View and right clicking on the *.rc but I don't know how to add the RC_BINARYTYPE part

Answer (score 5):

In VisualStudio 2015, MOHW's answer didn't help me but this worked:

program.rc file:

```
IDR_TIMS_FILE         RCDATA      "C:\\Users\\Tim\\Desktop\\Binary.dat"
```

program.cpp file:

```
src = FindResource(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(id), RT_RCDATA);
```