# How do i put raw binary data from file into Windows resource file and extract in into void* in my program?

Tags: c++, windows, resources, sdl

I need this for putting .png tileset into the EXE file for later use in SDL.
I think i should use something like

```
IMG_Load_RW(SDL_RWFromMem(data, sizeof(data)), 0);
```

So i need to get data. I've heard about getting bitmap data into HBITMAP from resource files, but putting abstract binary data there is still a mystery for me.
Explain it if it's possible.

Comment: [FindResource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648042.aspx), [LoadResource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648046.aspx), [LockResource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648047.aspx). Also: [Introduction to Resources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468900.aspx).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740164/how-to-embed-link-binary-data-into-a-c-dll, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16527973/load-resource-as-byte-array-programmaticaly-in-c, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16592865/adding-a-binary-file-to-resource-in-visual-studio, and plenty of other answers on Google